# How to execute a command from controller in background?

Tags: php, symfony4

I have created a command in Symfony. This will run and insert data into the database. I have already tested and it is running fine.

Now my problem is I need to execute this command from the web interface where user clicks on the button and this insertion needs to take place. This insertion will take about 30-45 minutes. So I need to run it in background.

I have heard about `Process` in Symfony.

So I have created a controller with a route which when called executes following lines.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;


$process = new Process('php bin/console app:import:records' . '  > NUL');
$process->run();
return new Response('successfully done', Response::HTTP_OK);
```

But nothing is happening. It only displays last respnose message.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Comment: What do you mean "But nothing is happening"? You have checked that your action is not done? Is your PHP execution time big enough?

Comment: Can't I use Process?

Comment: @Ihor I was expecting `('php bin/console app:import:records` to keep running in background.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966/6651840)

Extract from the link above....

---

Assuming this is running on a Linux machine, I've always handled it like this:

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

This launches the command `$cmd`, redirects the command output to `$outputfile`, and writes the process id to `$pidfile`.

That lets you easily monitor what the process is doing and if it's still running.

```
function isRunning($pid){
    try{
        $result = shell_exec(sprintf("ps %d", $pid));
        if( count(preg_split("/\n/", $result)) > 2){
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){}

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RabbitMQ for this. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html
Push message with information about action, then recieve that message in consumer and do the work.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html

Comment: Thanks. But I need quick solution at the moment. No time for rabbitMQ